# Parsing both dd-MM-yyyy and yyyy-MM-dd to Date type in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format, date

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        
      DateFormat date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
      System.out.println(date.parse("18-09-2017")); //Doesn't give an error but output is incorrect
      System.out.println(date.parse("2017-09-18"));  //Output is correct.
    }
}
```

How can I parse both the Strings containing date in different fashion.
NOTE: I need the output of parse in java.util.Date type.

Comment: So you need to seperate formatters, you can try parsing then input string with one and it it fails, use the other

Comment: the date.parse(...) will work for both. It won't give any error, but the output is incorrect. The issue is that this parser won't fail. If it did, I could just parse it with the other formatter in the catch block, but it doesn't fail. Gives an incorrect output though.

Comment: If you "absolutely, must, without question" use an Java 7 or below, then you can use `date.setLenient(false);` to force the formatter to be more stringent about it's parsing process

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

After [getting a `LocalDate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62505831/642706), convert to a `java.util.Date` object representing the first moment of the day on that date as seen in UTC, to satisfy your requirement of a `java.util.Date` object as a final result.

```
java.util.Date
.from( 
    myLocalDate
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )
    .toInstant() 
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62505831/642706) is correct, you should be using *java.time* classes for all new code doing date-time handling. These modern classes are a *gigantic* improvement over the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. The older classes became obsolete [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

### Converting from modern *java.time* classes to legacy classes

Your Question requires a `java.util.Date` as a result. To interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, the old classes have been retrofitted with conversion methods.

The legacy type replaced by `java.time.LocalDate` is [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html) – notice the `sql` in the middle versus the `util` you asked for.

```
java.sql.Date javaSqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( myLocalDate ) ;
```

Unfortunately, the `java.util.Date` object you want is not a direct fit. That class represents a moment, a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC. A date alone has no time-of-day and no time zone or offset-from-UTC. So, square peg, round hole.

One workaround is to use the first moment of the day on that date as seen in UTC.

```
Instant instant = myLocalDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant() ; // First moment of the day on that date as seen in UTC. 
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

> How can I parse both the Strings containing date in different fashion.

You really should use individual formatters for each pattern you need.  Since it's 2020, you really should be making use of the `java.time.*` API introduced in Java 8 or the back port project if you can't use Java 8.

For example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input1 = "18-09-2017";
        String input2 = "2017-09-18";

        System.out.println(QuickFormatter.parseDate(input1));
        System.out.println(QuickFormatter.parseDate(input2));
    }

    public static class QuickFormatter {

        static DateTimeFormatter pattern1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        static DateTimeFormatter pattern2 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE; // yyyy-MM-dd

        public static LocalDate parseDate(String input) {
            try {
                LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(input, pattern1);
                return ld;
            } catch (DateTimeParseException exp) {
                System.err.println("Failed to parse input using firstpattern");
                try {
                    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(input, pattern2);
                return ld;
                } catch (DateTimeParseException exp2) {
                    System.err.println("Failed to parse input using second pattern");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Could easily modify this to make use of a array or `List` to maintain the patterns you support or pass those as a parameter to the `parseDate` method - this is just an example of the idea

Comment: But I need the date in java.util.Date type. Implementing this would mean that I have to make a lot of changes to my project.

Comment: @HARSHITDANG Understand that `java.util.Date` and it's supporting classes (including `Calendar`) are considered as "soft deprecated" - it's strongly encouraged that you stop using them and start making the change to support the `java.time` APIs - Since Java 8 was release in 2014 - there's really no more excuse not to - just saying

Comment: @HARSHITDANG To address the `java.util.Date` part of your Question, I added [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62508294/642706) as a sequel to this correct Answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### java.time.LocalDate

You can do it easily using the Java 8+ Time API, since [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) supports optional section using `[...]` in the pattern.

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd-MM-yyyy][yyyy-MM-dd]");
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("21-06-2020", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2020-06-21", formatter));
```

*Output*

```
2020-06-21
2020-06-21
```

---

#### java.util.Date using java.sql.Date

If you need a `java.util.Date`, you can use the helper method in the [`valueOf(LocalDate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-) method in the [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) subclass:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd-MM-yyyy][yyyy-MM-dd]");
java.util.Date date1 = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("21-06-2020", formatter));
java.util.Date date2 = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2020-06-21", formatter));
System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(date2);
```

Same output.

---

#### Plain java.util.Date

If you don't like the use of `java.sql.Date`, the logic becomes a bit more complex, so I'd suggest a helper method.

```java
static java.util.Date parseDate(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd-MM-yyyy][yyyy-MM-dd]");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return java.util.Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
}
```

Or as a single statement:

```java
static Date parseDate(String date) {
    return Date.from(LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd-MM-yyyy][yyyy-MM-dd]"))
                              .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                              .toInstant());
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(parseDate("21-06-2020"));
System.out.println(parseDate("2020-06-21"));
```

*Output*

```
Sun Jun 21 00:00:00 EDT 2020
Sun Jun 21 00:00:00 EDT 2020
```

Comment: For when you know the formats up front, this is neat

Comment: I beg to differ in the last part: If you need a `java.util.Date` for a legacy API, you should not settle with a `java.sql.Date`. It probably works, but it is not what that class is meant for. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. Ok, I'll grant you that. Added alternative to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to define individual formatters for each pattern. You can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to include both the patterns in a single formatter.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .appendPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd]")
                                    .appendPattern("[dd-MM-yyyy]")
                                    .toFormatter();

        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("18-09-2017", formatter);
        LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("2017-09-18", formatter);

        System.out.println(date1);
        System.out.println(date2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-09-18
2017-09-18
```

You should stop using outdated and error-prone date-time API from `java.util` package and start using [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from `java.time` package and its sub-package(s).